# bitcoind: listtransactions return error `Unknown named parameter from`

Tags: bitcoind

I want to return a list of wallet transactions via rpc command and set count and offset, but this query

```
{"method":"listtransactions","params":{"from":"0","count":"1"},"id":1}
```

returns error message `Unknown named parameter from`. I read manual  https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Original_Bitcoin_client/API_calls_list and took those fields from there. But seems something not working or I set it wrong? If I skip params, rpc works just fine

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you're sending commands via RPC you need to refer to the [Bitcoin RPC API Reference](https://developer.bitcoin.org/reference/rpc/index.html).

Upon looking specifically at [`listtransactions`](https://developer.bitcoin.org/reference/rpc/listtransactions.html) you will see that there is no `from` parameter:

```
Argument #1 - label
Argument #2 - count
Argument #3 - skip
Argument #4 - include_watchonly
```

You may be confusing the client API with RPC commands (most of which have similar or related command names but have different parameters and syntax).

In this case, `from` probably correlates to `skip` which indicates the number of transactions to skip over before returning the transactions indicated in `count`.